# What is the difference between several types of Ninject instantiation approaches in WebAPI 2 project

Tags: ninject, asp.net-web-api2, owin

There are several Ninject packages available for WebAPI 2 project.

Package number 1: [Ninject.Web.WebApi](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi/3.2.3)

This one just adds these references

[image]

No code file is added. Ninject injection just works for ApiControllers as a constructor injection for example. It is unclear where to add Modules to be loaded into Kernel but it works.

Package number 2: [Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi.WebHost/3.2.3)
Adds the same set of references and the NinjectWebCommons.cs, a standard WebActivator hook that injects IoC into the application operation and provides a point to add Modules to a kernel, also works in WebAPI 2 VS template.

Package number 3: [Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Ninject.Web.WebApi.OwinHost/3.2.3)
This one adds more references then any other:

[image]

Documentation for the package advises Ninject to be injected via a call like this:

```
app.UseNinjectMiddleware(CreateKernel).UseNinjectWebApi(webApiConfiguration);
```

Also works to inject dependencies in WebAPI 2 template and provides a place to configure IoC.

What are the difference between these three packages (the fundamental one). Which way of linking Ninject into a web app is a preferred one, if such criteria can be applied.

Thank you.